# NET 6 - Entity Framework Core Error: SQL Server was not found or was not accessible

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-6.0

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API (VS 2022), and executing any controller API through swagger ui results in a connection to SQL Server error. Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmvcAzHpsk8) but implementing in .NET 6.

Part of error log:

> Entity Framework Core 6.0.7 initialized 'CommanderContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.7' with options: None
> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
>
> An error occurred using the connection to database 'CommanderDB' on server 'localhost'.
>
> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Commander.Data.CommanderContext'.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
> Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Connection string in `appsettings.json`, checked and matched with server explorer database property. Checked SQL Server was running in Configuration Manager and able to be accessed in SSMS. Executing `dotnet ef migrations add` successfully connects and also created table. Remote connections are enabled.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CommanderConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=CommanderDB;User ID=CommanderAPI;Password=1234;"
  }
}
```

Connecting in `Program.cs` with this code:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CommanderContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CommanderConnection")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICommanderRepo, SqlCommanderRepo>();
```

EDIT:

SQL Server Protocols SS:

[image]

Shared Memory and TCP enabled.

Comment: I'll bet you're using a named-instance of SQL Server but your connection-string doesn't specify the instance-name. Also, SQL Server uses `"(local)`" instead of "`localhost`" for local instances (as `localhost` is a network host-name, but SQL Server supports non-network transports like shared-memory). Anyway, try `Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;`.

Comment: I still get error 40 with (local) and with (local)\\SQLEXPRESS I get error 25, invalid connection string. (local)\SQLEXPRESS does not build, flagging as invalid escape sequence.

Comment: As this is JSON you need to backslash-escape the backslash (as `(local)\\SQLEXPRESS`) - but first have you actually **verified** that your SQL Server is running and has that instance-name?

Comment: Yes, shows SQL Server `(MSSQLSSERVER)` running in SQL Server Config. Tried `(local)\\MSSQLSERVER`, results in invalid connection string error.

Comment: Check your [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver16) and show us a screenshot of what you see under the "SQL Server Network Configuration" node. Also include screenshots of the Properties window for TCP/IP and Shared Memory.

Comment: Edited, added screenshot, TCP/IP was disabled, just enabled it, and restarted the SQL Server, but the error still occurs.

Comment: Are you able to connect using SSMS?

Comment: Yes, using same credentials (localhost), can access and write into the table

Comment: I'm stumped then, sorry.

Comment: Did you run dotnet ef database update after your first migration?

Comment: Yes, also just ran it again, and it said no migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.

Comment: Are you at home on your local internet or at work on a companies network?

Comment: Home local internet

Comment: Problem resolved: Was running on docker... changed to (project name) in visual studio and ran. Thanks for attempting to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, was running on docker so it wasn't able to connect to localhost. Switch to (project name).
[Dropdown split button options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ekR9.png)